# How to apply recommendation system algorithm on my data frame

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, apriori

I am trying to develop a recommendation system in python. I have processed input data by using pandas.Basically i am developing this application for E-Learning system. Session id stands user browsing session, return 1 if user go through the book1, if he is not going through book return 0. Our aim is  to recommend  other books once he is selecting a book. We can find out the other books read on previous data.
 This is how my processed data look. 
I was thinking about apply Apriory algorithm to find the output. is this enough to 
apply apriory algorithm? .or shall i use any other methods. I found some examples. But still confused how 
i could apply this on my case.I am new to python and machine learning ? can some one guide how i could resolve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on meanings of the "0" and "1" in feature columns? What is "session_Id"?

Comment: Session id stands user browsing session, return 1 if user go through the book1, if he is not going through book return 0. Our aim is  to recommend  other books once he is selecting a book. We can find out the other books read on previous data. I have processed data to this format. if that is not suitable i can alter that

Comment: In short, you may use `apriori`, `collaborative filtering`, `ALS` or any other recommendation method on this data. See this link for a summary of recommendation methods https://towardsdatascience.com/various-implementations-of-collaborative-filtering-100385c6dfe0. Any book from Packt or O'reilly on recommendation engines may be helpful too